# Vector based programs like Paint Tool SAI?

Tags: vector

Dose anyone know a program that has the the curve, edit, and pressure features that SAI has? I like how you can make a line and then just add points with the edit button. The pressure tool is really great too. Are there any vector based programs that are as easy to use as SAI?

Comment: Hi Welcome to GDSE. Paint Tool SAI isn't actually vector software.  It's raster software with some vector functionality.  The closest for free is probably Krita. Ease of use is subjective.

Comment: I've never used Sai.. but Adobe Illustrator + DynamicScribe (from AstuteGraphics.com) will do most, if not all, of what you are asking. None of it is free though.

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with Paint Tool SAI, but the specific things you mention remind me of two apps:

[**Affinity Designer**](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/designer/) 
and 
[**Concepts App**](https://concepts.app/en/)

Both are vector-based, have excellent brush engines, and allow simple editing after the fact (add a point, recurve etc) and both have really solid pressure systems for tablets - Affinity Designer also allows manual editing of the pressure curve of a stroke after the fact which is great for working with a mouse but still having curve dynamics; Concepts has some amazing approaches to vector based but still painterly that set it completely apart from other vector design and art programs.

Hope this helps.